# How to use a backspace character to delete a few characters using Ruby and Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium

Here is the flow I would like to use:

- Copy with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.
- Paste the result in a textfield with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>.
- Cut the last bit of the pasted text (`@yopmail`)

I'm using Ruby and Selenium. I don't have any errors, just that if I use `\b` it just prints `\b` and if I use `\ue003` nothing happens.

I don't seem to get the deleting part working. I already was able to simulate the copy/paste with keys but I don't know how to put the backspace to work. Here is what I have:

```
require "rubygems"
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver::Keys 
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://www.yopmail.com/"


driver.find_element(:xpath, "//b").click
sleep 1
driver.find_element(:id, "login").click
sleep 1 

driver.action.key_down(:control)
             .send_keys("a")
             .key_down(:control)
             .send_keys("c")
             .key_up(:control)
             .perform

driver.navigate.to "http://www.yopmail.com/"

driver.find_element(:id, "login").click
sleep 1
driver.find_element(:id, "login").clear

driver.action.key_down(:control)
             .send_keys("v")
             .key_up(:control)
             .perform
sleep 1
driver.find_element(:id, "login").click
    driver.action.send_keys("\ue010")
                .send_keys("\ue003")
                .send_keys("\ue003")
                .send_keys("\ue003")
                .send_keys("\ue003")
                .send_keys("\ue003")
                .send_keys("\ue003")
                .perform
```

Everything is working fine until I try to use the backspace (`\ue003`). For what I know, `\ue010` does nothing either.

I know that if I just go back the website already has `@yopmail` stripped down but this is a test and the final product won't have it this way, so I really need to understand how to properly simulate a backspace in order to delete a few chars

Comment: Why are you using `"\ue010"`? A backspace character is, like you said, `"\b"` -- or `"\u008"`.

Comment: "\ue010 is for END key I believe, so the cursor is set at the end. This way I'm sure I will erase what I want with the backspace :)

Comment: END is `\u0003`, if we're talking about [regular ASCII encoding](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: This is quite a bizarre test, anyway... Is it really necessary to test the copy+paste functionality?! Or, could you not just *read the value* of `driver.find_element(:id, "login")` and then enter this (without the final `@...` part) into the other text box? I think you've really overcomplicated this.

Comment: I think you know more than me about this so I changed the code, but still, it doesn't reach the end of the textfield neither do it use the backspace :/

Comment: Actually, I tried this way because I thought it was easier, as I was just following my functional testing. I'll try what you said and let you know, thank you.

Comment: Just in case, I should have said it, but I'm fairly new to coding in general and I usually end up trying different things until it works...

Comment: `login = driver.find_element(:id, "login").text; ... ; driver.action.send_keys(login.sub('@yopmail', ''))`